# root mean square in numpy and complications of matrix and arrays of numpy 

Tags: python, numpy

Can anyone direct me to the section of numpy manual where i can get functions to accomplish root mean square calculations ... 
(i know this can be accomplished using np.mean and np.abs .. isn't there a built in ..if no why?? .. just curious ..no offense)

can anyone explain the complications of matrix and arrays (just in the following case):

`U` is a matrix(T-by-N,or u say T cross N) , `Ue` is another matrix(T-by-N)
I define `k` as a numpy array

`U[ind,:]` is still matrix

in the following fashion
`k = np.array(U[ind,:])`

when I print `k` or type `k` in ipython

it displays following

```
K = array ([[2,.3 .....
              ......
                9]])
```

You see the double square brackets (which makes it multi-dim i guess)
which gives it the shape = (1,N)

but I can't assign it to array defined in this way

```
l = np.zeros(N)
shape = (,N) or perhaps (N,) something like that

l[:] = k[:]
error:
matrix dimensions incompatible
```

Is there a way to accomplish the vector assignment which I intend to do ... Please don't tell me do this `l = k` (that defeats the purpose ... I get different errors in program .. I know the reasons ..If you need I may attach the piece of code)

writing a loop is the dumb way .. which I'm using for the time being ...

I hope I was able to explain .. the problems I'm facing ..

regards ...

Comment: In the future, please do not combine two questions together in the same post. It will make it easier for people to respond and for future users of the sight to find things.

Comment: If you inspect the shape attribute of various arrays (e.g. `K.shape` or `l[:].shape`) you will see whether the dimensions of the arrays are incompatible, and it will give you clues about how you might correct the issue.

Comment: Quite a verbose question, indeed. As pointed already, if you have two questions, ask two questions then. Anyway, just show your actual code and there's good change that you'll get constructive suggestion. Just, your current way to ask the (simple) questions makes them actually quite cumbersome. Thanks

Comment: Could you please clarify exactly what type of RMS calculation you want to do (either by citing an equation or linking to the definition that you are using)?

Comment: @JoshAdel  thanx josh for your comments ... yeah from next time onwards ... i'll post one question at a time .. exactly what type of rms .. well i want to take a row of a matrix and substract it with an array, the resulting sequence i want to average (in mean squared sense) .. i know my question is a lot verbose i thought it would help me in expressing my question .. rather proved to be opposite of it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
U = np.zeros((N,N))
ind = 1
k = np.zeros(N)
k[:] = U[ind,:]
```

Comment: Small correction: Should be `U = np.zeros((N,N))`, otherwise you'll get an error.

Comment: thanx highBandWidth and JoshAdel ...this should do ... can you suggest a refernce where i can see this kind of information .. (i'm looking into numpy for matlab users .. is that good enough?)

Comment: I got this mainly through trying to use scipy/numpy.

Comment: @chwi, N is the dimension of the matrix you want. It is a number, like 5 if you want a 5x5 matrix.

Answer (score 90):

For the RMS, I think this is the clearest:

```
from numpy import mean, sqrt, square, arange
a = arange(10) # For example
rms = sqrt(mean(square(a)))
```

The code reads like you say it: "root-mean-square".

Comment: I often work with complex data, in that case square isn't enough. You need something like `abs(a)**2`

Comment: Indeed.  Or you could do `a*conj(a)`, which *should* be more efficient, although I haven't benchmarked it.

Comment: That may be the most elegant formulation of a non-trivial algorithm I've ever seen. And it's useful, too! Bravo.

Comment: doesn't `np.std(a)` do the same thing?

Comment: @Rainb: No, it is not the same *unless* `np.mean(a) == 0.0`

Comment: Personally, I prefer avoiding importing each function from the numpy library. Consider using, import numpy as np, and then use np.mean, np.sqrt instead.

Answer (score 13):

For rms, the **fastest** expression I have found for small `x.size` (~ 1024) and real `x` is:

```
def rms(x):
    return np.sqrt(x.dot(x)/x.size)
```

This seems to be around twice as fast as the `linalg.norm` version (ipython %timeit on a *really* old laptop).

If you want complex arrays handled more appropriately then this also would work:

```
def rms(x):
    return np.sqrt(np.vdot(x, x)/x.size)
```

However, this version is nearly as slow as the `norm` version and only works for flat arrays.

Answer (score 8):

For the RMS, how about

```
norm(V)/sqrt(V.size)
```

Comment: upvote because it is concise but norm is from `np.linalg` instead of directly from `np` and it does not have an optional `axis` argument, useful to make the rms function more general

Comment: @dashesy [`np.linalg.norm`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) does have an `axis` parameters since version 1.8.0.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know why it's not built in. I like

```
def rms(x, axis=None):
    return sqrt(mean(x**2, axis=axis))
```

If you have nans in your data, you can do

```
def nanrms(x, axis=None):
    return sqrt(nanmean(x**2, axis=axis))
```

Comment: I often work with complex data, in that case square isn't enough. You need something like `abs(x)**2` instead of just `x**2`

Answer (score 1):

I use this for RMS, all using NumPy, and let it also have an optional `axis` similar to other NumPy functions:

```
import numpy as np   
rms = lambda V, axis=None: np.sqrt(np.mean(np.square(V), axis))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have complex vectors and are using `pytorch`, the vector norm is the fastest approach on CPU & GPU:

```
import torch
batch_size, length = 512, 4096
batch = torch.randn(batch_size, length, dtype=torch.complex64)
scale = 1 / torch.sqrt(torch.tensor(length))
rms_power = batch.norm(p=2, dim=-1, keepdim=True)
batch_rms = batch / (rms_power * scale)
```

Using batch `vdot` like [goodboy's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28398092/760099) is 60% slower than above. Using naïve method similar to [deprecated's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7433184/760099) is 85% slower than above.