# Average RMS value of an 3D audio signal in Python

Tags: python, audio, rms, energy

I am quite new to programming and Python. I am working on a project in which I built an Auditory filterbank with two banks of Gammatone filters. Now I ended up with a 39x10x8545 matrix. I want to calculate the average of rms energy across the time axis (over the 8545) to reduce the dimensionality of the signal. Can anyone suggest me a better method to do it efficiently in Python because I cannot afford much memory due to the audio signal being very large. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried just averaging the signal using numpy.mean along the time axis, but I am not sure if they are both the same

Comment: If both what are the same?

Comment: The mean and the RMS values... I know that they are not the same but don't know how the numpy.mean worked. Now I am clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RMS of is signal is the root mean squared, which is not the same as the mean. So you need to perform the RMS calculation.

```
math.sqrt(numpy.mean(x*x))
```

There are several other pages on this site that discuss this in further: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613244/root-mean-square-in-numpy-and-complications-of-matrix-and-arrays-of-numpy), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245687/numpy-root-mean-squared-rms-smoothing-of-a-signal), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197492/root-mean-square-error-in-python)

Comment: Hi Dave... Thanks for the answer but as I told, I have to find a mean across the 3rd axis in 3D array.. I will give it a try anyway.

Comment: Sure, well in python you can select the first row of a matrix with x[1,:], if its a np array, so this could be extended to whatever dimension of matrix you have. How are you building your array, as I believe the standard python array module does not support multidimensionality.

Comment: It does, I had a 39x10x8495 matrix as I said. I just used the equation you gave me to find the RMS of all the 8495 elements and then put them into a 39x10. It works, thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer this question myself based on Djmoffat's answer. I tried his answer but found that the numpy.pow() gave me very slow results. So I tried using

```
math.sqrt(numpy.mean(x**2))
```

This gave me faster results. I understand that `math.pow()` is slow as it has to consider many other things like fractional powers and other things clearly discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327002/which-is-faster-in-python-x-5-or-math-sqrtx). The context is important as I am sure I will have just the integer powers and more precisely '2'.